# I receive this error when i use kivy in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My Code is :

```
    from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

And i receive :
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Alok.kivy\logs\kivy_20-08-15_45.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\kivy_*init*_.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\core_*init*_.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in 
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

I use Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands and let me know if it works or not

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

after this run the program again and check for errors

Comment: what is your kivy version installed ??